# How to display a result based on a sum as sum inputs are entered

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, variables

I am tring to work out a price with VAT included based on a VAT rate the user enters. I want to display the result in a input box. Can I display the result of this as the user enters the VAT rate and price without clicking a button or resubmitting the form.

I am using this to work out the price with VAT.

```
<?php
    $taxprice = ($tax * $selling)
?>
```

`$tax` is the value of the input box where the user enters the tax rate.
`$selling` is the value of the input box where the user enters the price.
`$taxprice` is the value I want displayed in an input box as the user enters the values for the other two fields.

I cant get the sum to work live as the user enters the two values without using a button. Does anybody know how to do this? Thanks Jon :)

Comment: Do you want to process this computation in browser or server?

Comment: Just in browser, for the user to see. I wont be saving the result to my database.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the value to update without submitting the form you'll need to use Javascript.

Something like this might suffice:

```
// Execute the function() {} when the page loads
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    // Get the button that is clicked to calculate the tax
    var calcbutton = document.getElementById('calculateButton');

    calcbutton.addEventListener('click', function() {
        // Get the tax amount from an input with an ID of "taxValue"
        var tax = document.getElementById('taxValue').value || 0;
        // Get the selling price from an input with an ID of "sellingPrice"
        var sellingPrice = document.getElementById('sellingPrice').value || 0;

        // Calculate the taxed amount
        var taxPrice = sellingPrice * tax;

        // Set the value of an input with an ID of 'taxedPrice' to the calculated taxed price
        document.getElementById('taxedPrice').value = taxprice;
    });
});
```

You might want to look into using the 'keyup' event on the inputs for the tax and price values to reflect the taxed value immediately after the price or tax changes.

E.g.

```
// Assuming page is loaded

var taxInput = document.getElementById('taxValue');
var sellingPriceInput = document.getElementById('sellingPrice');
var taxedPriceInput = document.getElementById('taxedPrice');

taxInput.addEventListener('keyup', calcTaxPrice);
sellingPriceInput.addEventListener('keyup', calcTaxPrice);

function calcTaxPrice() {
    var tax = taxInput.value || 0;
    var sellingPrice = sellingPriceInput.value || 0;

    var taxPrice = sellingPrice * tax;

    taxedPriceInput.value = taxprice;
}
```

Comment: That code looks great. But how do I display the result in a input box without loading the page?

Answer (score 0):

### Do it client-side with Javacript

The basic pattern for a client-side calculator with jQuery:

```js
$(function () {
    $('#a').on('input', function () {
        var a = parseFloat($(this).val()),
            b = parseFloat($('#b').val()),
            c = a * b;
        $('#c').val(c);
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="calc">
    <label>Enter a number:<br />
      <input type="text" id="a" />
    </label><br />
    <label>Multiplier:<br />
      <input readonly type="text" id="b" value="0.0725" />
    </label><br />
    <label>Calculated value:<br />
      <input readonly type="text" id="c" />
    </label>
</form>
```

It is comprised of three components: user input, pre-defined input *(optional)*, calculated output.

An easy way to pre-define input and make the user aware of it, is to use an `input` text field with the `readonly` attribute.

The same type of `readonly` `input` may be also conveniently be used for the output if you want it to remain a part of the form. You may also choose to display the output in a `div` or other container element that can be more easily styled.

For "live" updating use the listen to the `input` event. *(This event isn't compatible with IE8 or older. Alternatively, listen to 'keydown' when the input has focus.)*

Note: Use `parseFloat` to convert text input into floating point numbers which can be calculated without the risk of returning `NaN`. Additionally, you should use some kind of input restriction and/or validation to prevent unexpected values.

Comment: Pls don't use query unless the question asks for it. Plain Javascript is enough here. No need to use external libraries for such a simple function

Comment: jQuery was one of the selected tags. Assuming the user already had the library available to them, this is a quick and convenient solution.